Filter Users by AppRoleAssignments.ResourceId using GraphServiceClient on C#
I'm trying to use GraphServiceClient to get a set of users which have an AppRoleAssignment with a specific ResourceId. I've researched enough to know that this should be doable (second example here, also here the ResourceId is said to support the filter by eq option), so I don't know what am I doing wrong.
I created this method to get the users that I want:
public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetAllUsersAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var clientSecret = options.ClientCredentials.First().ClientSecret;
    var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(options.TenantId, options.ClientId, clientSecret);
    var client = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, options.Scopes);

    List<User> users = new List<User>();

    UserCollectionResponse? userCollectionResponse =
    await client.Users.GetAsync(
        requestConfiguration => {
            requestConfiguration.Headers.Add("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual");
            requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Count = true;
            requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = ["id", "givenName", "surname", "mail", "userType"];
            requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = ["appRoleAssignments"];
            requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Top = 100;
            requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = string.Format("appRoleAssignments/any(a:a/ResourceId eq {0})", options.ServicePrincipal);
        });

    PageIterator<User, UserCollectionResponse> pageIterator =
        PageIterator<User, UserCollectionResponse>.CreatePageIterator(
                client,
                userCollectionResponse,
                (user) => {
                    var roles = user.AppRoleAssignments;
                    //if (roles != null && roles.Any(r => r.ResourceId.ToString() == options.ServicePrincipal))
                        users.Add(user);
                    return true;
                }
            );
    await pageIterator.IterateAsync();

    return users;
}

In theory this should work, but for some reason I'm getting this error:
Exception: Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError: Property 'resourceId' does not exist as a declared property or extension property.
First thing I noticed is that the ResourceId property appears in lowercase on the error, while I specified it with a capital R on my code. Aside that, I see no other problems with it, nor understand why it is failing.
While I'm able to get the users that I want without this filter an uncommenting the line with the if in the Iterator, I want to get the exact users I need from the query itself instead of having to manually filter them, if possible.
Any suggestions?

Both the links that you shared points to /approleassignments endpoint. The filters and expand that you are applied to is user endpoint. I believe that filtering the expanded item in a single call is not supported.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1010008/filtering-and-expanding-users

When you want to apply filter to an expanded property, you need to specify nested filter. requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = [$"appRoleAssignments($filter=resourceId eq {options.ServicePrincipal})"];. But it seems to me that nested filter is ignored

hey @ShivaKeshavVarma thanks for the reply, if you look closely on the first link the endpoint is graphClient.Users["{user-id}"].AppRoleAssignments.GetAsync, so firt and foremost is User, then an expanded section of AppRoleAssignments. Also if you look into the Advanced Queries documentation you can find the User -> AppRoleAssignments property to be compatible with the filter eq, so I'm pretty sure this should be doable. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=csharp
Also if that was the problem then the error should be more explicit, right? Seems odd to me

@user2250152 thanks for the tip, I tried it but yeah, trying to filter it like that didn't do anything, tried also as ResourceId (capital R) but to no avail. I'm trying out changing the other filter (general filter) and to add more confusion if I change the filter to "appRoleAssignments/any(a:a/RResourceId eq {0})" I get the error Exception: Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError: Invalid filter clause: Could not find a property named 'RResourceId' on type 'microsoft.graph.appRoleAssignment'. which is similar to the original, but this one looks more legit... still no clue tho

You have RResourceId, it should be ResourceId

Yes, I know, I tested it like that to see what happened with the de-capitalization that I mentioned before (from ResourceId to resourceId), and as you can see not only it changes the Exception message (which is similar) but it also doesn't de-capitalize the RResourceId property name that I used in the filter string.
I'm inclined to think there is a bug on the parser which processes this specific filter and the decapitalization is what's causing the error, but I have no way to confirm that, and honestly I'm pretty new to this API so I might be missing something

As far as I have seen, this issue is likely because you are trying to filter users by AppRoleAssignment's ResourceId directly on the Users endpoint. The Microsoft Graph API doesn't support filtering on nested properties in this way.
You can get the AppRoleAssignments for a specific ResourceId, then you can get the users from these assignments.


var appRoleAssignments = await graphServiceClient.ServicePrincipals[roleId.ToString()]
    .AppRoleAssignedTo
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

List<User> users = new List<User>();

foreach (var assignment in appRoleAssignments)
{
    var user = await graphServiceClient.Users[assignment.PrincipalId.ToString()]
        .Request()
        .GetAsync();

    users.Add(user);
}



